# Python code for read/write binary file and convert it to .pcap

Tags: python-2.7, binaryfiles, ethernet, pcap, ipv4

I want to write a python script that reads a binary file (have no extension but when open in hex viewer software, IPv4 packets presents), search 45 in file, reads 3rd and 4th byte for determining the length of IP packet, then write all the packet in other file. Repeat all this until file completely reads. Save the new file.
After that, the new saved file should be converted into pcap by using text2pcap utility.

When I use text2pcap utility, it reads the expected packets in that binary file but wrote 0 packets.
I want to convert this binary file into pcap for further analysis by using wireshark as I know that IPv4 packets presents in it without any header of IPv4 and ethernet headers.

Comment: Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. You above Q isn't suitable for this site, because it's not a specific question related to a specific programming problem. Rather, it's a project/task description. Anyhow, just one suggestion: Don't use an obsolete Python 2.7 but Python 3. There, try to find a parsing library for the input file, rather than writing your own. In order to write one yourself, take a look at the `struct` module.

Comment: The "text" in "text2pcap" means it's a program that reads text files, not binary files.  Is your Python script writing the packet out in a text format supported by text2pcap?  And what is the binary format of the file you're trying to read?  What happens if you try to open it in Wireshark?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ulrich Eckhardt for suggestion. Will you please let me know where should I post this question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.